# Cocoapods - No such file or directory for custom script

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a private Cocoapods library that I import into my project. The library has a script which runs everytime before compiling, that works perfectly locally on my workspace but once you use the pod remotely by default CocoaPods removes all files that are not matched by the source files

How can I include these scripts into my source files without adding them to my classes as I don’t want to add them to xcode project

Here is what is inside of my Podspec:

```
    s.script_phase = [

        { :name => 'the name of my script',
          :script => 'cd ${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT} && ./myscript',
          :execution_position => :before_compile 
        }
      ]

  s.source_files = ['Classes/**/*{h,m,swift,json,strings,xib,storyboard}']

  s.preserve_paths = 'myscript.swift'
```

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/faW7I.png]

Comment: Without knowing, did you try to do a "pwd" (before/after the "cd"), a "ls" to know where you are? Try `${PODS_ROOT}` instead of `PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT`?

Comment: it seems like you're not including the folder containing `myscript` file in the pod. try changing the path or adding it to the array of `s.source_files`